# How to add dynamic route prefix in nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, multilingual

I want to add a dynamic language based on API. In API I get list of languages and I should have route prefix for each language except en.

for example:

```
en:
https://mynuxt.com/hotel/paris-hotel

de:
https://mynuxt.com/de/hotel/paris-hotel

and ...
```

How should I generate my dynamic routes? and languages are dynamic.

Comment: Does this help: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-nested-routes

Comment: @Kalimah can you make example of this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example on how to create the folder structure to provide the desired router path:

`pages/
--| _lang/
-----| hotel/
-------| paris-hotel/
---------| index.vue
--| hotel/
----| paris-hotel/
------| index.vue`

Then you can import a view into both `index.vue` to avoid duplicating logic. Ofcourse, I could be more of a help if your provided an example of what you have tried so far.